# Siteswap validator

Tags: code-golf

[Siteswap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siteswap) is a notation for juggling patterns.

The other [siteswap puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25178/juggling-by-numbers) is great and it explains siteswap in greater detail than here. This puzzle is meant to be a bit simpler! Numberphile recently [interviewed](https://youtu.be/7dwgusHjA0Y) Colin Wright which helped develop the notation. The part at [~16min](https://youtu.be/7dwgusHjA0Y?t=15m51s) will be useful for this challenge. Another resource which may be useful for wrapping your hear around siteswap if you have not used it before: [In your head](http://www.siteswap.org/validate.html)

Below is the diagram(courtesy of wikipedia) for valid throws with 3 balls and a max height of a throw of 5. A valid siteswap ends at the same position as it started.

[image: siteswap diagram 3 balls max height 5]

A valid siteswap for the case we are interested in is defined as follows: In the diagram above choose a starting node and then follow the arrows and write down the number attached to the arrow. If you end up on the same node as you started then the number you have written down is a valid siteswap, otherwise it is not valid.

#### Challenge

Take a number as input and output a truthy value if it is a valid siteswap for juggling with 3 balls with a max height of 5, otherwise output a falsy value. (No multiplex throws are allowed)

#### Examples

```
Input             Output
------------------------
3                  True
3333333333         True
3342               True
441                True
5                  False
225225220          False
332                False
```

- [Loopholes that are forbidden by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/29750) are not allowed.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins.

Comment: I've voted to close this as unclear; challenges should provide all the required information rather than linking to other challenges and sites. As it stands, nothing in the challenge defines a valid siteswap nor can a definition be easily inferred from the test cases. In the future, please consider [Sandboxing](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/58974) your challenges.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/25178/38183)? Certainly related.

Comment: @shaggy I hope my edit clarifies it; now the links serve more as additional background rather than primary explanation

Comment: I think it is pretty clear now (the first 2 paragraph is background information, the next 2 paragraph and the image describe the challenge). Given that we need to compress the graph, this challenge is somewhat like a kolmogorov-complexity one.

Comment: Can we take the siteswap as a list of numbers instead of a single number?

Comment: That would be ok

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>204</s> <s>195</s> <s>188</s> <s>174</s> <s>149</s> 144 bytes

```python
lambda s:any(i==reduce(lambda C,c:int('40WW75W5AA47WW07W4WW54A0WWAA70A5WAA123896W'.replace('W','A'*3)[C::11][int(c)],16),s,i)for i in range(10))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxBDsIgEEX3noIdYIgBCqJNuiAeYhbqAitVkkobWheeHqsxWic/mbyfmdc/xmsXZW6qQ27d7XR2aChdfJBQVcmf77Unn3rH6jLEkWDFAYwGba0yANyAAtDKTq21hls9LSGLzXYNeJV837rJgQEzbPGyoPtdWQpx3L9UNT0ysaZsYIE2XUIBhYiSixdPBKc092m6Qg3BBaaLH3znv1VyzkqJOeo5SKnf4f@C139@Ag)